# Batch update for RIA in SL5

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

c#
I need to update 4 objects (entities) that exits on a observableCollection. 
if they are not bound to the view (UI)

1. What's the best way or How they should be updated using RIA?
2. I would not like to create 4 trips to the database.
3. Would this gerenate 4 sql update commands?
4. What about if there is a time frame while the User decides what to change, could be other user changing one of the entity. if so what?
5. Any links I could read related to these questions ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

should at least know what kind of update you need to do, basing on your question I'm just assuming that you need the user to change some arbitrary values on some entities, so, no "optimizations" and Group update can be done.

1. The domaincontext will keep track of your changes and send them as a whole in single Changeset.
2. The number of trips that you'll do to the database it's not related to WCF Ria services, rather it's a feature of your data layer, however, if you are using an ORM like nHibernate take a look at it's batchsize, or for EF take a look at his extension: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2011/11/29/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries.aspx
3. Normally yes. Any out of the box data layer solution I know of, will generate 4 distinct updates
4. this is known as **Concurrency**. Again, is something that you should manage at your data layer. Raising an exception if other user have changed that row is a reasonable way in most case
5. take a look at this http://blogs.infosupport.com/optimistic-concurrency-with-wcf-ria-services-and-the-entity-framework/

I suggest you to reformulate your question into more specific arguments. Actually it's too wide, each point requires analysis of your needs and it's impossible to indicate a way.

Comment: thanks so much mCasamento, your assumption is correct on the update.(the update: to keep it simple, lets say the entity has two properties: code , description so the user can change them and he changes 4 descriptions and changes are kept in the observablecollection)